# Fetching the max value from ROWS in pentaho

Tags: max, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have a table structure

```
ID  Col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
1    34     23     45     32
2    20     19     67     18
3    40     10     76     86
```

I here want the max value from col_1,col_,col_3,col_4 so my output looks like

```
 ID   Col_1   col_2  col_3  col_4  max
    1    34     23     45     32   45
    2    20     19     67     18   67 
    3    40     10     76     86   86
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use a Modified Java Script Value step with the following code:

```
var max = Math.max(col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4);
```

Comment: unfortunately you cannot use Calculator, AFAIK, so you need to use custom Java Script as described in this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Memory Group By` or `Group By` steps in Pentaho. Use the aggregation method as "Maximum" based on your grouping id.