# Transposing the data in order to get the max value from column in pentaho

Tags: max, transpose, kettle, pentaho-spoon

With the reference to my previous question [Fetching the max value from ROWS in pentaho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634275/fetching-the-max-value-from-rows-in-pentaho)

I'm trying to transpose the rows to column using row-denormaliser but i;m not able to get the desired result, any method will do(the ultimate aim is to get the max value from the rows). kindly help
[image]

Comment: number of columns are fixed?

Comment: In the reference post yes it is fixed and in this post the column I'm trying to transpose as to get the max value of the column(my ultimate aim to to get the max value from the rows)

Comment: according sample in previous question. u don't need any transpose. just use JavaScript Step to find max amongst them and bind this value to new column

Comment: the thing is, if the number of columns are fixed, you can use JavaScript step to match values from the row.